# How can I deploy my web app on something like GitHub Pages or Netifly if I don't upload files with sensitive data in them?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, frontend, github-pages

For example, I have a config file where I store keys such as client id and client secret. I've put this config file in my .gitignore so that it won't be pushed with the rest of my project, but how would the versions on GitHub and Netifly run the project correctly if it isn't able to access that config file?

Is there some way to keep the config file private (without making the entire GitHub repo private) while still including it in the files on a hosting site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On this case, you have some ways to do that:

- Use Environment variables [doc](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables)
- Use an external API where you can fetch your secret data.

Comment: env variables won't work since they will be included in the build and accessible by inspecting the code https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/ the only safe way to do it that I know is storing them in the server-side.